# UNC symlink on a vm box return as it's not a directory in java

Tags: java, windows, unc

i have a code that check if directory file is a directory and it's working very well on Host Machine Win/Lin but problem is on any VM running on Virtual Box or VMWare Player. The code block bellow returns false in Guest OS and true on HOST OS which is weird.

The command that i'm using to create symlink UNC path is:

```
mklink /D "C:\Program Files\app\repository\repo" \\192.168.1.x\public\repo
```

java code block:

```
private boolean directoryExists(File newDirectory) {
    return newDirectory.isDirectory();
}
```

Host OS: Windows 10 x64
Guest OS: Windows 10 x86/x64, Windows 7 x86, Windows 6.1 x64

Comment: Maybe your Guest OS does not have sufficient permission to that directory ?

Comment: when i double click from windows explorer it's working i can browse UNC path from symlink